# PHP images not displaying. Works in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I'm building a website and I'm attempting to reuse code for a scrolling photo banner.

I can mock-up everything pretty well within a strict html page.  So I decided to move everything over to PHP to help make things more efficient and with the intent of eventually using MySQL in other content on the site.  However, after I created my functions and began to plug everything in the photo banner disappeared.  Everything else including the CSS displays beautifully.  I went so far as to remove the CSS from the page to see if that was the problem.  Unfortunately the images still refuse to show up.  It was a direct copy->paste from the working HTML document so I'm not totally sure why the photos for the banner aren't appearing.  Any advice or help would be great.  Here's the code:

```
<html>
<style>
@import "honeysstyle.css";
</style>
<div id="container">
<div class="photobanner">
    <img class="first" src="C:\wamp\www\Honeys Project\honeys\Image1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="C:\wamp\www\Honeys Project\honeys\Image2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="C:\wamp\www\Honeys Project\honeys\Image3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="C:\wamp\www\Honeys Project\honeys\Image4.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="C:\wamp\www\Honeys Project\honeys\Image5.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="C:\wamp\www\Honeys Project\honeys\Image1.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="C:\wamp\www\Honeys Project\honeys\Image2.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="C:\wamp\www\Honeys Project\honeys\Image3.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="C:\wamp\www\Honeys Project\honeys\Image4.jpg" alt="">
</div>
</div>
<?php
require( 'function.php' );

draw_titlebar();
draw_navigation();



?>

</html>
```

Comment: make your image path relative to server

Comment: Have you debugged the requests going over the wire, with a tool like [Fiddler?](http://www.fiddlertool.com/)

Comment: What do `draw_titlebar()` and `draw_navigation()` do?  Please post that code.

Comment: If `C:\wamp\www` is your server root, then just use `<img src="Honeys\ Project\honeys\ImageX.jpg">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
<img class="first" src="C:\wamp\www\Honeys Project\honeys\Image1.jpg" alt="">
```

to

```
<img class="first" src="honeys/Image1.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm assuming the reason the PHP wasn't working is because it's a server side script rather than HTML which seems to be more relative to your browser?  Excuse the stupid question I haven't built a site in about 5 years so I'm extremely rusty.

Comment: nop the issue is with path actually, if you try the same code with .html file you wont get the image.. the right way to call a local file is `src="file://C:\wamp\www\Honeys Project\honeys\Image1.jpg"` i think.. just for a sake of check try it..

Comment: also dont forget to select any of the answer as a right answer.. :)

Comment: It actually works in an HTML document the way I originally had it setup.  I basically just started copy->pasting from an html mock-up since I at least wanted a framework.  That's why I was so confused.  At least it works in Chrome.  I haven't started tinkering with the other browsers yet.

Answer (score 1):

image path should be like this

```
    <img src="http://localhost/Honeys Project/honeys/Image2.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: Or even better, omit `http://localhost/` and just request `Honeys Project/honeys/Image2.jpg`. The space in the folder name might, or might not break the request though.